# Протокол telnet или что-то подобное

Tags: php, сокет, telnet

Возник вопрос при обдумывании web-проекта. Пишу как только могу, поэтому простите за возможные непонятки. Требуется что-то наподобие такого:
Есть игровой сервер (cs 1.6), требуется с сайта подать команду на включение этого сервера, и наоборот. Т.е. когда захотел - включил, когда захотел - выключил. Но хотя бы это для начала, далее требуется посылка RCON команд на сервер, но, думаю, с этим проблем не будет, если сделать первое. Я уже писал насчет данной проблемы, но так конкретного ответа не получил. Кто-то говорил о telnet, но о данном протоколе я не нашел информации в Интернете, как им пользоваться в моем случае; другие предлагают использовать готовые скрипты, но и они подводят (доставать скрипт, не зная его алгоритм действия, не по-умному). Кто понял, о чем я толкую, то большая просьба поделиться своими знаниями, как все-таки это сделать, описать алгоритм. Заранее огромное спасибо, т.к. уже мучаюсь невесть сколько...

Данное реализовано на: fastcup.net / fragarena.ru

Comment: игровой сервер и веб сайт на одном сервере?

Comment: Нет, разумеется, отдельно.

Comment: Тогда я не помог.

Comment: Очень жаль. (

Comment: Разместить скрипты управления на одном сервере с игровым. Посылать к ним команды с другого сервера, на котором веб-сайт. Так не получиться?

Comment: @Дмитрий Астафьев, говоря "сервер", Вы имеете в виду железо (с ОС) или программу?

В состав серверов (железа) HP входит компонент ILO, у IBM - IMM, у Dell - не помню, но тоже есть аппаратный компонент со своим IP адресом, позволяющий получить удаленный доступ (по сети, в т.ч. через web-интерфейс) к hardware console (ну, конечно, физически включить в шнур питания в розетку он не может -)).

Если Вам нужно что-то подобное, то просто купите подходящее железо...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это два вопроса.

1. Чтоб запустить/остановить exe'шник (любой), понадобится какое-то админское приложение типа [PsTools](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx) для удаленного выполнения команд (это если без допсофта на стороне сервера с CS), либо какая-то прога должна стоять на серевере CS и запускать hlds.exe с соответствующими параметрами, а php-сайт к ней коннектился бы и посылал соответствующие команды... Для линуска (если CS сервер линуксовый) соответственно свои методы.
2. Для общения с сервером через RCON уже можно соединяться напрямую (без дополнительного софта) с сервером CS по UDP на соответствующий порт. И общаться по этому RCON протоколу. Для CS:S вот [ссылка](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/RCON) есть, для обычного CS может подойти, либо должно быть свое описание... Вот пример скрипта (найдено в интернетах) получающего статус сервера:

   ```
   $server = "192.168.0.250";   
   $stroka = "\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\x54\x53\x6F\x75\x72\x63\x65\x20\x45\x6E\x67\x69\x6E\x65\x20\x51\x75\x65\x72\x79\x00"; 
   $fp = fsockopen("udp://".$server,"27016"); 
   fwrite($fp, $stroka);   
   echo fread($fp, 128);   
   fclose($fp);
   ```

Comment: Да, там же у valve есть готовые классы общения с сервером по RCON, но опять-таки для Source.

Comment: А как на сервер это все реализовать? Ведь на сервере нету exe файла,) только на локалке.

Comment: @Дмитрий Астафьев, в смысле только на локалке? На сервере запускается сервер hlds.exe. У вас есть три машины:  

* сервер CS (там запускается hlds.exe);
* web-сервер (PHP из которого вы будете коннектитьтся к CS-серверу); 
* клиент, на котором отображается страница в браузере и, видимо, сам cs-клиент впоследствии. 

Для начала вам надо суметь запустить  CS-сервер удаленно. Как? Варианты в ответе.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.

Answer (score 1):

Это надо сделать 1 раз

```
apt-get install openssh-server
```

Создаешь ключ командой

```
ssh-keygen -t dsa
```

Кидаешь его на удаленный созданный (новый сервер) командой

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub root@ipudalennogoservera
```

Затем `ssh root@ipudalennogoservera` подключение к удаленному серверу

```
cd /home/cs3
```

`screen -A -m -d -S cs3 ./hlds_run -binary ./hlds_linux -game cstrike +maxplayers 26 +ip ipudalennogoservera +port 27018 +map aim_sk_ak_m4 -pingboost 3` -  запуск сервера

`screen -rd cs3` – подключение к консоли сервера для команд в консоли cs